# Function to filter data equal to or greater than a certain value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing thousands of rows and columns. The rows contain the names of genes and the columns the names of samples.

I only want to keep the rows that contain a value equal to or greater than 5 in more than 3 samples.

I tried this so far but I can't figure out how to set multiple conditions:

```
data.frame1 %>% filter_all(all_vars(.>= 5))
```

I hope I have stated this question correctly.

Comment: Let us see what you data looks like

Comment: So rowwise >5 (same genes) appearing in more than three columns? can there be more than 1 gene listed in a row in a column? So  out there in dplyr verbs, you're looking at rowwise(), n_distinct() >= 5 and jeez, the columns (samples) >3?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a small example of your data and expected output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The question has already been answered to my satisfaction but for future purposes what would be a good way to give an example of my data? When I use print(dataframe1) and copy the output and paste it here as a code the table is all over the place and does not give a nice overview of the data.

Comment: @Tezie you can use `dput(head(data))` and copy-paste the output. For instance try `dput(head(mtcars))`. The output should start with `structure(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it in my gene expression filtering pre-differential gene expression pipeline is as follows:

```
data.frame1[rowSums(data.frame1 >= 5) > 3, ] -> filtered.counts
```

And if your first column is your gene identifier, with all the other columns being numeric, you can have the evaluation skip the first column as follows:

```
data.frame1[rowSums(data.frame1[-1] >= 5) > 3, ] -> filtered.counts
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this in `dplyr 1.0.0` is

```
iris %>% 
    filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)) > 6) > 1)

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
2          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
3          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
4          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
5          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
6          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
7          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
etc
```

For your case

```
data.frame1 %>%
    filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)) >= 5) > 3)
```